# Create multiple ZipArchiveEntry in ZipArchive class with different extensions C#

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to figure it out how to create a zip archive that contains files with different extensions e.g. .txt file, .html file

If I do following:

```
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memory, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    var file1= zipArchive .CreateEntry("file1.html");
    var file2= zipArchive .CreateEntry("file2.txt");

    using (var entryStream = file1.Open())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write("testing testinsg steing");
    }

    using (var entryStream = file2.Open())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
    {
        sw.Write("xyxyxyxyxyxy");
    }
}
```

> Entries in create mode may only be written to once, and only one entry
>   may be held open at a time.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to move down the line:

```
var file2= zipArchive .CreateEntry("file2.txt");
```

... and place it ***after*** you've finished writing to the previous entry:

```
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memory, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    var file1= zipArchive .CreateEntry("file1.html");

    using (var entryStream = file1.Open())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write("testing testinsg steing");
    }

    var file2= zipArchive .CreateEntry("file2.txt"); // <-- move this down
    using (var entryStream = file2.Open())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
    {
        sw.Write("xyxyxyxyxyxy");
    }
}
```

Comment: A damn, 2 seconds too late ^^. The term `open` is a bit misleading in that error message. What it actually should say is `Don't create another entry until the previous one was closed`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thank you bro!